# Gauss Law - charges outside the gaussian surface

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I have just learned Gauss Law and this question is bothering me:

Suppose a cubic gaussian surface and a charge next to its right side (image below). According to Gauss Law, the electric flux over this surface is:

$\unicode{x222F}_S \overrightarrow{E}.\overrightarrow{dA}= \frac{Q_{int}}{\epsilon_0} = 0$

But, as we can see, the flux depends on the electric field at different points. If the absolute value of the flux on the right side is larger than on the left side, why is it inconsistent  to say that the total flux on this surface is negative?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every "flux line" that enters the cube, there is another "flux line" that leaves the cube, that is why the total flux is zero.